# programmatically access a d3 rectangle on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, rect

I create a few d3 rectangles and give them each a click event:
First I created the container:

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("#Container")
                                .append("svg")
                                .attr("width", 720)
                                .attr("height", 45);
```

then in a for-loop I create each rectangle inside the container:

```
var rectangle = svgContainer.append("rect")  
                                        .attr("x", 10 + xAppend)
                                        .attr("y", 5)
                                        .attr("width", 120)
                                        .attr("height", 35)
                                        .attr("stroke", "black")
                                        .attr("name", name)
                                        .on("click", function () {
                                            // Click event...
                                            //...
                                        });
```

Now in a different function, I want to trigger that on-click function. The variable 'rectangle' is not global, it gets created inside the for loop and I create 6 rectangles from the for loop.

What I have done so far inside the other function is:

```
var tempContainer = d3.select("#Container");
var test = tempContainer.selectAll("rect");
```

This gives me a array of 1 object and that object is an array of the 6 rectangles, then I loop through the array to find the rectangle I want.

```
for (var i = 0; i < test[0].length; i++) {
    if (search.item.desc == test[0][i].attributes[5].value)
    {
        var testing = test[0][i];
        //testing.attributes[5].value   works fine
        //testing.click();       does not work
        //testing.on('click')();        does not work
    }
}
```

Inside the for-loop the variable 'testing' is the rectangle I want, I can access its attributes like I did in the if statement above. But I cannot access and trigger the on click function.

Comment: The duplicate you mentioned does not work for me. I read it, tried the answers, hence why I posted in my question that ".on ("click");" does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The on-click event function can be accessed by using the following:

```
testing.__onclick();
```

Comment: Could someone explain why there needs to be "__" before the onclick();